# How do I merge the following tables in sequence when the key columns are different?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have been requested to merge several tables in a specific order. The first table, 'a', serves as a directory with some basic information for each entity, uniquely identified by 'id'. The second and third tables each have specific information for each entity and sub-entity, defined by 'id' and 'groupid'.

I have been asked by a colleague if it is possible to get 'd' by first merging 'a' with 'b' and then merging the result with 'c'. I've tried various combinations of full and cross joins but nothing seems to get the result. After merging tables 'a' and 'b', using 'id', I then have to figure out how to keep three possible of results:

1. rows where 'id' and 'groupid' are the same in both tables, and
2. rows where 'id' and 'groupid" are present only in the previous step, and
3. rows where 'id' and 'groupid" are present only in the table c.

How can I merge tables 'a', 'b', and 'c' (in that order) to get 'd'?

Note: I am aware that I can merge tables b and c first and then merge a. This question's focus concerns mainly the order constraint.

```html
library(data.table)
set.seed(15)
a <- data.table(id = c(1:10), info = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5))
a
#>     id info
#>  1:  1    A
#>  2:  2    A
#>  3:  3    A
#>  4:  4    A
#>  5:  5    A
#>  6:  6    B
#>  7:  7    B
#>  8:  8    B
#>  9:  9    B
#> 10: 10    B
b <- data.table(id = c(rep(c(2:3), each = 2), rep(c(5:6), each = 3)), groupid = rep(c(1:3), times = 3), info2 = round(rnorm(10), 1))
#> Warning in as.data.table.list(x, keep.rownames = keep.rownames, check.names
#> = check.names, : Item 2 has 9 rows but longest item has 10; recycled with
#> remainder.
setorder(b, id, groupid)
b
#>     id groupid info2
#>  1:  2       1   0.3
#>  2:  2       2   1.8
#>  3:  3       1   0.9
#>  4:  3       3  -0.3
#>  5:  5       1   0.0
#>  6:  5       2   0.5
#>  7:  5       3  -1.3
#>  8:  6       1  -1.1
#>  9:  6       2   1.1
#> 10:  6       3  -0.1
c <- data.table(id = c(rep(c(1:2), each = 3), rep(c(4:5), each = 2)), groupid = rep(c(1:4), times = 2), info3 = round(rnorm(10), 1))
#> Warning in as.data.table.list(x, keep.rownames = keep.rownames, check.names
#> = check.names, : Item 2 has 8 rows but longest item has 10; recycled with
#> remainder.
setorder(c, id, groupid)
c
#>     id groupid info3
#>  1:  1       1   0.9
#>  2:  1       2  -0.4
#>  3:  1       3   0.2
#>  4:  2       1   1.5
#>  5:  2       2   0.0
#>  6:  2       4  -1.2
#>  7:  4       3   0.0
#>  8:  4       4   0.0
#>  9:  5       1  -1.2
#> 10:  5       2  -0.5
d <- data.table(id =      c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6),
                groupid = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                info =  c('A', 'A','A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
                info2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.3, 1.8, NA, 0.9, -0.3, NA, NA, 0.0, 0.5, -1.3, -1.1, 1.1, 0.1),
                info3 = c(0.9, -0.4, 0.2, 1.5, 0.0, -1.2, NA, NA, 0.0, 0.0, -1.2, -0.5, NA, NA, NA, NA))
d
#>     id groupid info info2 info3
#>  1:  1       1    A    NA   0.9
#>  2:  1       2    A    NA  -0.4
#>  3:  1       3    A    NA   0.2
#>  4:  2       1    A   0.3   1.5
#>  5:  2       2    A   1.8   0.0
#>  6:  2       4    A    NA  -1.2
#>  7:  3       1    A   0.9    NA
#>  8:  3       3    A  -0.3    NA
#>  9:  4       3    A    NA   0.0
#> 10:  4       4    A    NA   0.0
#> 11:  5       1    A   0.0  -1.2
#> 12:  5       2    A   0.5  -0.5
#> 13:  5       3    A  -1.3    NA
#> 14:  6       1    B  -1.1    NA
#> 15:  6       2    B   1.1    NA
#> 16:  6       3    B   0.1    NA
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're producing questionable frames? Don't ignore the warning here.

Comment: *"rows where 'id' and 'groupid' are the same in both tables"*, table `a` does not have `groupid`.

Comment: In table `b`, where `id == 2` and `groupid == 1`, `info2` is `2.1`, but in table `d` it's `0.10`, and likewise for many other values. Are there errors in your example data or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to a dplyr solution, you can left-join `a` and `b`, full-join the result with `c`, then use `tidyr::fill()` and `drop_na()` to clean up the results:

```r
library(dplyr) # >= v1.1.0
library(tidyr)

a %>% left_join(b, multiple = "all") %>% 
  full_join(c) %>% 
  arrange(id, is.na(info)) %>% 
  fill(info) %>% 
  drop_na(groupid) %>%
  relocate(id, groupid)
# Joining with `by = join_by(id)`
# Joining with `by = join_by(id, groupid)`
```

```
    id groupid info info2 info3
 1:  1       1    A    NA   1.3
 2:  1       2    A    NA   0.0
 3:  1       3    A    NA  -0.5
 4:  2       1    A   0.2  -1.2
 5:  2       2    A   1.5  -0.6
 6:  2       4    A    NA  -1.5
 7:  3       1    A  -0.5    NA
 8:  3       3    A   0.5    NA
 9:  4       3    A    NA  -0.4
10:  4       4    A    NA   0.3
11:  5       1    A   0.1   0.5
12:  5       2    A  -0.3  -0.3
13:  5       3    A   0.7    NA
14:  6       1    B  -1.5    NA
15:  6       2    B  -0.3    NA
16:  6       3    B   0.9    NA
```

`info2` and `info3` don't match the values in your example output `d`, but they *do* match the values in tables `b` and `c` -- are you sure table `d` is correct?